# Create a pseudo column to display Yes/No if one column value is present in another for a particular id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the following structure :

```
create table test_18Nov ( account_id nvarchar(12)
                        , account_name nvarchar(25)
                        , zip_legacy_file nvarchar(5)
                        , Region_legacy_file nvarchar(30)
                        , zip_new_source nvarchar(5)
                        , Region_new_source nvarchar(30)
                        )

INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '32221', 'R087-Jacksonville',   '33803', 'R026-Lakeland')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '33606', 'R011-Tampa',          '32220', 'R087-Jacksonville')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '33803', 'R026-Lakeland',       '33606', 'R011-Tampa')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33606', 'R011-Tampa',          '32205', 'R087-Jacksonville')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33870', 'R058-Sebring',        '33606', 'R011-Tampa')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33610', 'R011-Tampa',          '33870', 'R058-Sebring')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('AC077', 'Stacey Leigh',     '34950', 'R043-Fort Pierce',    '34982', 'R043-Fort Pierce')
INSERT INTO test_18Nov VALUES ('AC077', 'Stacey Leigh',     '33610', 'R011-Tampa',          '34950', 'R043-Fort Pierce')
```

I have to generate a pseudo column for all rows with either Yes or No.
For an account id if the legacy region(or regions) is present in new source region(or regions) then the pseudo column will display 'No'. If for an account a new source region (or regions) is not present in legacy region (or regions) then the account will be considered as a move and the pseudo column will display 'Yes'. In the above data set AC054 is the only account id that should have the pseudo column value as 'Yes' because R087-Jacksonville (a new source region) is not present in the legacy region list.

The expected output should be :

```
account_id  | account_name      |  Region_legacy_file   | Region_new_source     | Will the account move?    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S1018       | John Smith        | R087-Jacksonville     | R026-Lakeland         |       No                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S1018       | John Smith        | R011-Tampa            | R087-Jacksonville     |       No                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S1018       | John Smith        | R026-Lakeland         | R011-Tampa            |       No                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC054       | David Thompson    | R011-Tampa            | R087-Jacksonville     |       Yes                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC054       | David Thompson    | R058-Sebring          | R011-Tampa            |       Yes                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC054       | David Thompson    | R011-Tampa            | R058-Sebring          |       Yes                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC077       | Stacey Leigh      | R043-Fort Pierce      | R043-Fort Pierce      |       No                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC077       | Stacey Leigh      | R011-Tampa            | R043-Fort Pierce      |       No                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I thought of using NOT EXISTS clause but that will return only the rows where new source region is not found in the list of legacy regions for an account id - which is not of any help to me in this situation. Only way I can think of is using CASE WHEN EXISTS but have not been able to get it to work. If there is any other way please do share.

EDIT :
Why AC054 has the pseudo column as 'Yes'? - There are 3 new source regions for account id AC054 and they are R087, R011 and R058. Out of these 3 regions 2 regions are found in legacy regions for account id AC054 and they are R011 and R058. So R087 is not a part of legacy region list for account id AC054 and hence the pseudo column has 'Yes'. For the other 2 account ids that is not the case because all the new source regions are found in the legacy region list.

Comment: to be honest i still, i can't understand your criteria for true and false

Comment: If you have it working for one row, rather than the whole account, use window functions to spread the result of the remaining rows. `MAX(your_expression) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS move_yes_no`

Comment: @nbk - If you look at the data for account id AC054 you will note that both the legacy regions are present in new source regions. But R087 from new source region is not present in legacy region. Is that still not clear?

Comment: @Arty155 no i really don't see how sevrina and tampa are related to another, so i don_'t see wh the should be moved at all, there must be an underlying table that explain why which combination fits and another don't

Comment: @nbk - There is no other table and there is no geographical connection. I have just given an example. The values might as well be Region 1-ABC, Region 2-TGV, Region 3 or any character combination one can think of. The logic is for a particular account id the  new source region should not be present in legacy region. I have edited the expected output in my opening post. Hopefully fewer columns could help in visualizing the data.

Comment: @MatBailie - My query does not give the output I have posted here. I will post my query but I would like to repeat again : the query does not give the desired output.
`select o.*,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from test_18Nov i where i.account_id = o.account_id and i.Region_new_source <> o.Region_legacy_file) THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No' END as Will_the_account_move
 from test_18Nov o`

Comment: @Arty155 So, I suggested you wrap your CASE expression in the window function I gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm checking your information and I did a sample what a sub query CheckLegacy will return the account what should be moved, follows the example:

```
WITH test_18Nov  AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '32221', 'R087-Jacksonville',   '33803', 'R026-Lakeland'), 
        ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '33606', 'R011-Tampa',          '32220', 'R087-Jacksonville'), 
        ('S1018', 'John Smith',       '33803', 'R026-Lakeland',       '33606', 'R011-Tampa'), 
        ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33606', 'R011-Tampa',          '32205', 'R087-Jacksonville'), 
        ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33870', 'R058-Sebring',        '33606', 'R011-Tampa'),
        ('AC054', 'David Thompson',   '33610', 'R011-Tampa',          '33870', 'R058-Sebring'),
        ('AC077', 'Stacey Leigh',     '34950', 'R043-Fort Pierce',    '34982', 'R043-Fort Pierce'),
        ('AC077', 'Stacey Leigh',     '33610', 'R011-Tampa',          '34950', 'R043-Fort Pierce')
    ) AS _ (account_id,account_name, zip_legacy_file,Region_legacy_file,zip_new_source,Region_new_source)
),
--formatting the query for the field I need
IdAndNewLegacy as (
    SELECT account_id, Region_new_source FROM test_18Nov
),
--check if some new legacy region is not in Region_legacy_file
CheckLegacy as (
    SELECT I.account_id, T.account_id as id FROM IdAndNewLegacy as I
    LEFT JOIN test_18Nov as T ON I.account_id = T.account_id and I.Region_new_source = T.Region_legacy_file
    WHERE T.account_id is null
    GROUP BY I.account_id, T.account_id
)
--Query to present the data
SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN c.account_id is not null then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as [Will the account move?]
FROM 
    test_18Nov  as t
    LEFT JOIN CheckLegacy as c ON T.account_id = C.account_id
```

The result:

[image: Query Result]

Best Regards

Comment: Thank You @Diego ! That worked and it was fast. The actual table I am working on has almost 250k records and your query finished in 4-5 seconds. My sincerest thanks to you. I have marked this as an answer.

Comment: No need to include `T.account_id AS id` or include it in the `GROUP BY` clause. Also, pleae don't include data or results as linked images, it goes against SO's best practices. See here; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE expression *(Or `IIF()`)* to get YES/NO (using a NOT EXISTS check) for each Row.

Then use `MAX(expression) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id)` to give all account rows YES is ANY of them are yes.

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  MAX(
    IIF(
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM Test_18Nov
         WHERE account_id         = t.account_id
           AND region_legacy_file = t.region_new_source
      ),
      'YES',
      'NO'
    ) 
  ) OVER (PARTITION BY t.account_id)
FROM
  test_18Nov   AS t
ORDER BY
  t.account_id,
  t.region_new_source
```

DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/rOS1OoFe

Comment: Thanks Mat! This also worked. I was originally trying to go the this route but I did not know of IIF function. I will have to study up on IIF function. Thanks for sharing an alternate way to achieve this. Can a post have 2 answers? I want to make this also a solution to my problem.

Comment: @arty `IIF(boolean, x, y)` == `CASE WHEN boolean THEN x ELSE y END` in fewer characters. --- You can't have two accepted answers, you either have to keep your choice or change your mind.

Comment: @arty I also noticed you had `EXISTS( WHERE = AND <> )` but that' s very different from `NOT EXISTS ( WHERE = AND = )`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a SQL subquery, which means that for each row you execute another query that looks up a result, for example:

```sql
SELECT name, id, location, (SELECT TOP 1 'exists' FROM location l WHERE l.location = c.location) 
FROM customer c
```

Comment: customer c and location l are 2 different tables. I have only one table. Also self join is on account id but the comparison on the 2 kinds of regions - legacy and new source.

Comment: This was an example; you can figure out how to apply the concept to your own query.